# Can the mass of air bubble in material medium be considered negative?

Tags: gravity

When I was going through the chapter of "GRAVITATION" from high school level physics book, I encountered a problem with a statement made. I couldn't make out the clear vision regarding the following:
"Mass of air bubble in the material medium is negative. So air bubbles inside water attract each other by the gravitational force  which is attractive in nature because of negative masses of both bubbles.
But an air bubble gets repel from a metal sphere inside water.Here gravitational force is repulsive, due to the negative mass of air bubble and positive mass of metal sphere."
I wish someone could simplify it in understandable form with reasons.
Thank you.

Comment: @count_to_10: this is a standard computational device. The gravitational field of an object with a hole is the same as that of a solid object added to a negative mass object the same size as the hole. That is in effect the positive and negative masses cancel to leave a hole. It is of course **just** a computational device.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70709/what-are-the-forces-acting-between-two-air-bubbles-in-water